# CUDA threads and blocks explanation

Tags: cuda

I have been following a tutorial here
http://www.nvidia.com/docs/IO/116711/sc11-cuda-c-basics.pdf

trying to teach myself basic GPU programming. I still don't quite understand the topology of blocks and threads. On page 42 the code defines size data as follows:

```
#define N (2048*2048)
#define THREADS_PER_BLOCK 512
```

Is this tutorial making assumptions? I'm currently on a laptop with a Nvidia 520m GPU. using the structure cudaDeviceProp I was able to determine that I am capible of running 1024 threads per block. What exactly does the 2048x2048 quantify? The number of blocks? how do I know if that is correct?

Answer (score 1):

The `N` (2048*2048) quantity is the overall size of the data set.  This problem is a vector add problem, so the overall size of the vectors to be added is `N` elements.

Threads per block is already defined at 512.

The number of blocks can be determined from the kernel launch:

```
add<<<N/THREADS_PER_BLOCK,THREADS_PER_BLOCK>>>(d_a, d_b, d_c);
       ^                          ^  
    number of blocks            number of threads in each block
```

So the total number of blocks in the grid being launched is 2048*2048/512 = 8192

These particular parameters (512 threads per block, 8192 blocks total) should be compatible with any currently available CUDA GPU.

Comment: Ok, so if I understand you correctly. this 2048*2048 is a conservatice data set size or total number of threads. One that will work with ALL current GPU. When I run GPU Z get this info.
1 multiprocessor (48 cores)
1536 threads per MP
threads per block 1024
thread dimensions 1024x1024x64
grid dimensions 65535x65535x65535

Does this mean I should be able to run with 1024 threads per block and 1024x1024x64 threads. or am I limited to 1536 threads, which would be far less than what this code specifies?

Comment: I would highly recommend reading the first few sections of the c programming guide.

Comment: You're not limited to 1536 threads.  CUDA threadblocks do not all have to be scheduled at the same time.  They can be scheduled one after another, to whatever extent the hardware permits.  As I've stated already, 8192 blocks of 512 threads each should work **on any currently available CUDA GPU**, including yours.  It's not going to be possible to give you a complete CUDA tutorial in the space of a single SO question or a set of comments.

Comment: Don't worry about it. Thanks for the help anyway. I'll just have to hunt around for a tutorial that give's a little more detail. Christian, Which programming guide are you referring to? Is this on the Nvidea developer website?